# Azure Service Bus , receive one message at a time HOW?

Tags: vb.net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Can someone please help how to modify this code to receive only one message at a time?

```
    Private Sub Button_SEND_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_SEND.Click
    Dim client As QueueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(My.Settings.connString, My.Settings.queueName)
    Dim message As New BrokeredMessage(TextBox_M2SEND.Text.Trim)
    client.Send(message)
    client = Nothing : message = Nothing
End Sub

' reading the message
Private Sub Button_READ_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_READ.Click
    Dim client As QueueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(My.Settings.connString, My.Settings.queueName)
    Dim options As New OnMessageOptions()

    options.AutoComplete = False
    'options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    client.OnMessage(Function(message)
                         Try
                             ' Process message from subscription.
                             Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "**High Messages**")
                             Console.WriteLine("Body: " + message.GetBody(Of String)())
                             Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + message.MessageId)
                             ' Console.WriteLine("Message Number: " + message.Properties("MessageNumber"))

                             ' Remove message from subscription.
                             message.Complete()
                         Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                             ' Indicates a problem, unlock message in subscription.
                             message.Abandon()
                         End Try

                     End Function, options)

    client = Nothing : options = Nothing
End Sub
```

I`m able to store multiple messages, but when I execute Button_Read it pulls all of them. 
How do I pull only one at a time?

Thank you.
Alex.

Comment: `options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1` BTW, creating and deleting a client on _every_  button click is not a good idea. You should create your client once and re-use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `client.Receive()` method to pull a single message.

Comment: Right, that's the one.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, can do I pull the data? I assume I have to replace client.OnMessage .... with client.Receive(). How do I get the body of the message/Message Id for instance?

Comment: @alex.s You'll get `BrokeredMessage` back, same as in `OnMessage`

Comment: I think I got it. I added the following:

         Dim onemessage As BrokeredMessage
        onemessage = client.Receive()
        Console.WriteLine(onemessage.GetBody(Of String))
        onemessage.Complete()